# how to add dynamic Active class on selected page

Tags: php, jquery, css

http://hotelshimlahill.com/demo/
this website I've made in bootstrap,
the header section including nav bar is coming from a separate file called 'header.php'
Now i want to add active class for each page on which user is visiting.
how can i do that? Kindly assist me.
Thankyou.

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your individual page such as `about.php`, `services.php`, you can do:

```
$currentPage = 'about'; // current page is about, do the same for other page
include('header.php');
```

Then in your `header.php`, you can check:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="<?php if($currentPage =='about'){echo 'active';}?>" ><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($currentPage =='services'){echo 'active';}?>" ><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or you can try to use jQuery as well:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('.nav li a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: except `window.location.href` will be the full URL inc domain name whereas href is likely to be relative paths. This will not work.

Comment: `window.location.pathname` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

All menu links are inside ul > li. so, give id to all li. and on each page by using jquery addClass "active" to li.

Comment: Or just add the `active` class in the php when the menu is created? Why wait for a JS event to fire?

Comment: I've only one file header.php, if I add active class on each menu item then all menus will be active.

Comment: use of jquery will be easier for your required result.

Comment: Can anyone paste the code, its easier to say do it in jquery or do it in whatever..so please..help me

Comment: @ZaibAzharRao I'm obviously not saying to add it on every single `li`, only the one that should be active, like the answer from Aditya

Answer (score 1):

in you bootstrap css you find this line i think it should be at line no 4841

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{
    background-color: #5C0000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }

you change this line as

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.active{
background-color: #5C0000;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

now in your project file find the section where the navigation generated those line

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">                     
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>                       
    <li><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="facilities.php">facilities</a></li>
    <li><a href="reservations.php">booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.php">testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="careers.php">careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactUs.php">contact Us</a></li>          
</ul>
```

then change it as accrodinly

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">                     
    <li><a href="index.php" <?php if($active=='Home') echo "class='active'"; ?>>Home</a></li>                       
    <li><a href="about.php" <?php if($active=='about') echo "class='active'"; ?>>about</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php" <?php if($active=='services') echo "class='active'"; ?>>services</a></li>
    <li><a href="facilities.php" <?php if($active=='facilities') echo "class='active'"; ?>>facilities</a></li>
    <li><a href="reservations.php" <?php if($active=='booking') echo "class='active'"; ?>>booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.php" <?php if($active=='testimonials') echo "class='active'"; ?>>testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="careers.php" <?php if($active=='careers') echo "class='active'"; ?>>careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactUs.php" <?php if($active=='contact') echo "class='active'"; ?>>contact Us</a></li>          
</ul>
```

then you  have to a litle bit change in every files that you have in navigation link
such as 
index.php
add this line at the top of the file that i mention on the navigation link

```
<?php $active ='Home'; ?>
```

and for about.php

```
<?php $active ='about'; ?>
```

I think it of course select of your active page 
thnaks