# How to add bootstrap class active in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

i want to know how to add class active in codeigniter when we separate the view into 3 file. such as :

- header.php
- page1.php ... page10.php
- footer.php

from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037396/how-to-add-dynamic-active-class-on-selected-page), there's no way how to do it when separated the view.

this my header look like:

```
<body class="skin-red">
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="main-header">
</header>
<aside class="main-sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">
          <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
          <div class="user-panel">
            <div class="pull-left image">
              <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/dist/img/admin.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left info">
              <p>Username</p>
              <small>Privilage</small>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- search form -->
          <!-- /.search form -->
          <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
          <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="sidebar">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Users</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user_man"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>User List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-hospital-o"></i> <span>Provider</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>provider"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Provider List</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Product Info</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>productinfo"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>List Product Info</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Procedure</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>procedure"><i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>Procedure List</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Link Customer Portal</a></li> -->
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-film"></i> <span>Video Upload</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Video Data</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Prosedur</a></li> -->
                <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Informasi NAB</a></li> -->
                <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Demo(Video)</a></li> -->
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> <span>Slide Show Wallpaper</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Slide Show Data</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Prosedur</a></li> -->
                <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Informasi NAB</a></li> -->
                <!-- <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Demo(Video)</a></li> -->
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> <span>Examples</span>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>user/login"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Login</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <!-- /.sidebar -->
      </aside>
</div>
</body>
```

to access the content, this is the how i do:

```
<section class="content">
.....
</section>
```

and this my footer view:

```
</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
<footer class="main-footer">
  <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
    <b>Version</b> 2.0
  </div>
  <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2015</strong> All rights reserved.
</footer>


</div><!-- ./wrapper -->

<script></script>
<script></script>

</body>
</html>
```

i want to made,when user click the treeview submenu it will become active,
right know when i click the treeview submenu. it will reload not become active.
in sample i downloaded AdminLTE active class define in each submenu page, such as menu - `<li class="active">submenu</li>`

regards,
bobby

cmiiw

================================================

i found the js code, it is in. app.js.

```
$.AdminLTE.tree = function (menu) {
  var _this = this;

  $("li a", $(menu)).click(function (e) {
    //Get the clicked link and the next element
    var $this = $(this);
    var checkElement = $this.next();

    //Check if the next element is a menu and is visible
    if ((checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      //Close the menu
      checkElement.slideUp('normal', function () {
        checkElement.removeClass('menu-open');
        //Fix the layout in case the sidebar stretches over the height of the window
        //_this.layout.fix();
      });
      checkElement.parent("li").removeClass("active");
    }
    //If the menu is not visible
    else if ((checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      //Get the parent menu
      var parent = $this.parents('ul').first();
      //Close all open menus within the parent
      var ul = parent.find('ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      //Remove the menu-open class from the parent
      ul.removeClass('menu-open');
      //Get the parent li
      var parent_li = $this.parent("li");

      //Open the target menu and add the menu-open class
      checkElement.slideDown('normal', function () {
        //Add the class active to the parent li
        checkElement.addClass('menu-open');
        parent.find('li.act').addClass('active');
        // parent_li.addClass('active');
        //Fix the layout in case the sidebar stretches over the height of the window
        _this.layout.fix();
      });
    }
    //if this isn't a link, prevent the page from being redirected
    if (checkElement.is('.treeview-menu')) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
};
```

here's the first schema of the layout.
in page.A `<li>` was active so page.B, when i click one of the it become active.
after slicing the page into codeigniter way, i separate into 3: header,content(body),and footer. 
i remove all the class in tag `<li>`..

i try to modify like thie below:

```
checkElement.addClass('menu-open');
parent.find('li').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

it wont work,
wonder if u guys had a ways.

sorry for my bad english :-D

Answer (score 1):

It is easy and work properly

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
var url=window.location
$('.treeview-menu a').each(function(e){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if(link==url){
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.treeview').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try `preventDefault()`

```
$('.treeview').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code
Put below code before body tag ends

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.treeview a').each(function(e){
        var pathname = window.location.pathname.split("/");
        var url= pathname[pathname.length-1];
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
       if(link==url){$(this).parent('li').addClass('active');}
    });
  });
```

and where it is written **" $("li a", $(menu)).click(function (e) {"**
put below line after it

```
  $('.treeview .active').removeClass('active');
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).addClass('active');
```

Comment: it work but, i can't load my page. it cause by `e.preventDefault();`
i tried to modify it, but it still wont work too. this is how i dow: `$('.treeview-menu li a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('active');` @nirmal

Comment: no my page doesn't reload bro. my menu and submenu place in header.php,i separated AdmintLte template.  in AdminLte active class where place in each page of menu or submenu. @nirmal

Comment: sorry i mean does url changes. because in that case header will come in new page in new manner, in that case there is different solution although I have that solution as well but want to confirm your condition.

Comment: i already added the code, i hope is that what you mean. thanks @nirmal

Comment: hi @nirmal, sorry for late response. I already tried the script but fail, now i found the javascript. it is in app.js. if you want to check, i write the code in my thread.

Comment: hi @nirmal sorry for late answer, i already tried it but fail.the link wont be able to direct when i click. maybe i'll try to shutdown the app.js from adminlte ver 2.0 by using jquery accordion or dropdown

Comment: sorry for late respon, i already tried but nothing when i click it. @nirmal

Comment: can you help me by one thing, if you can create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: i guess that's wont fit on jsfiddle, it has many related js and css also. or maybe you had simple suggestion way to do that.

Comment: ok do one thing give me link of website, you can there after remove it from comment once it's solved