# set active class for dynamically generated links in php

Tags: php, css

In my application there is a page where I generate dynamic links based on the data from mysql DB. My task is to set a `class="active"` for the selected link. If the links where static I can give active class using page name [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037396/how-to-add-dynamic-active-class-on-selected-page). But what to do in my case? Is there any way to get this done?

Here is my code:

```
                <div class="select-region clearfix">
                <input type="hidden" id="rgnId" name="rgnId">
                <input type="hidden" id="hltypId" name="hltypId">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>Select your region</li>
                     <li value="0"><a class="active" id="show_0" onClick="UAEHolydayDetails(0)">All<span class="badge"><?php echo $uaedetailscount?></span></a></li> 
                    <?php
                     $i=0;
                      while($rowrgn = $rsltrgn->fetchAssoc())
                      {
                      ?>
                        <li><a  id="show_<?php echo $rowrgn['rgnId']; ?>" onClick="UAEHolydayDetails(<?php echo $rowrgn['rgnId']; ?>)"><?php echo $rowrgn['rgnName']; ?><span class="badge">
                            <?php echo $rowrgn['regioncount'];?></span></a></li>  
                  <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

can anyone please help me

Edit 1

when I click any of these dynamic links it passes an `id` to the same page through js and the page will be filled with data from DB based on this paseed `id` like this:
`onClick="UAEHolydayDetails(<?php echo $rowrgn['rgnId']; ?>)"`

js:

```
<script>
function HolytypeDetails(id){
$('#hltypId').val(id);
window.location='uae-holidays.php?hltypId='+id;
}
</script>
```

in script the page in window.location is the page where the links are generated itself

Comment: Well, do you have any information about the currently selected region available?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. But here when I click any of the link an `id` is passed and the page is filled with data based on that id.

Comment: So you can access the current regions id with something like `$_GET['regionId']`? Then you could simply check if the current regionId is equal to the one you are currently echoing in the loop. `$rowrgn['rgnId'] === $_GET['regionId'] ? 'class="active"' : ''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. It's the same thing. You need to know your active item id and based on this information just chose the item you want.

```html
<?php
  $activePageId = 5;

  $i=0;
  while($rowrgn = $rsltrgn->fetchAssoc())
  {
?>
  <li <?php if($rowrgn['rgnId'] === $activePageId){ ?>class="active"<?php } ?>><a id="show_<?php echo $rowrgn['rgnId']; ?>" onClick="UAEHolydayDetails(<?php echo $rowrgn['rgnId']; ?>)"><?php echo $rowrgn['rgnName']; ?><span class="badge">
  <?php echo $rowrgn['regioncount'];?></span></a></li>  
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just use a selector to grab it via the href

Example with jquery:

```
$('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
```